# "java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer" thrown on the resource manager when launching Spark on Yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to launch a Spark job using yarn-client mode on a cluster. I have already tried spark-shell with yarn and I can launch the application. But, I also would like to be able run the driver program from, say eclipse, while using the cluster to run the tasks. I have also added spark-assembly jar to HDFS and point to it by adding (HADOOP_CONF_DIR env variable) to eclipse, although I'm not sure if that's the best way to go about this.

My application does launch on the cluster (as I can see it in the resource manager's monitor) it finishes "successfully" but without any results coming back to the driver. I see the following exception in eclipse console:

```
WARN  10:11:08,375  Logging.scala:71 -- Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, vanpghdcn2.pgdev.sap.corp): java.lang.NullPointerException 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$rowToRowRdd$1.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:56) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$rowToRowRdd$1.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:55) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:686) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:686) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:70) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 

ERROR 10:11:08,522  Logging.scala:75 -- Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times; aborting job 
INFO  10:11:08,538  SparkUtils.scala:67 --           SparkContext stopped
```

And I get the following in the ResourceManager log:

```
2015-10-22 10:10:42,603 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: assignedContainer application attempt=appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 container=Container: [ContainerId: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000001, NodeId: vanpghdcn3.pgdev.sap.corp:41419, NodeHttpAddress: vanpghdcn3.pgdev.sap.corp:8042, Resource: <memory:1024, vCores:1>, Priority: 0, Token: null, ] queue=default: capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:0, vCores:0>, usedCapacity=0.0, absoluteUsedCapacity=0.0, numApps=1, numContainers=0 clusterResource=<memory:24576, vCores:24>
2015-10-22 10:10:42,603 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: Re-sorting assigned queue: root.default stats: default: capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:1024, vCores:1>, usedCapacity=0.041666668, absoluteUsedCapacity=0.041666668, numApps=1, numContainers=1 
2015-10-22 10:10:42,603 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: assignedContainer queue=root usedCapacity=0.041666668 absoluteUsedCapacity=0.041666668 used=<memory:1024, vCores:1> cluster=<memory:24576, vCores:24>
2015-10-22 10:10:42,604 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.NMTokenSecretManagerInRM: Sending NMToken for nodeId : vanpghdcn3.pgdev.sap.corp:41419 for container : container_1445462013958_0012_01_000001 
2015-10-22 10:10:42,606 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000001 Container Transitioned from ALLOCATED to ACQUIRED 
2015-10-22 10:10:42,606 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.NMTokenSecretManagerInRM: Clear node set for appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 
2015-10-22 10:10:42,606 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: Storing attempt: AppId: application_1445462013958_0012 AttemptId: appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 MasterContainer: Container: [ContainerId: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000001, NodeId: vanpghdcn3.pgdev.sap.corp:41419, NodeHttpAddress: vanpghdcn3.pgdev.sap.corp:8042, Resource: <memory:1024, vCores:1>, Priority: 0, Token: Token { kind: ContainerToken, service: 10.165.28.145:41419 }, ] 
2015-10-22 10:10:42,606 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 State change from SCHEDULED to ALLOCATED_SAVING 
2015-10-22 10:10:42,606 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 State change from ALLOCATED_SAVING to ALLOCATED 
2015-10-22 10:10:42,606 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher: Launching masterappattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 
2015-10-22 10:10:42,608 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher: Setting up container Container: [ContainerId: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000001, NodeId: vanpghdcn3.pgdev.sap.corp:41419, NodeHttpAddress: vanpghdcn3.pgdev.sap.corp:8042, Resource: <memory:1024, vCores:1>, Priority: 0, Token: Token { kind: ContainerToken, service: 10.165.28.145:41419 }, ] for AM appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 
2015-10-22 10:10:42,608 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher: Command to launch container container_1445462013958_0012_01_000001 : {{JAVA_HOME}}/bin/java,-server,-Xmx512m,-Djava.io.tmpdir={{PWD}}/tmp,'-Dspark.eventLog.dir=','-Dspark.driver.port=57819','-Dspark.app.name=Sparca Application','-Dspark.executor.memory=1g','-Dspark.master=yarn-client','-Dspark.executor.id=driver','-Dspark.externalBlockStore.folderName=spark-10391661-8d35-40d9-8242-fe79bdc19d2d','-Dspark.fileserver.uri=<a href="http://10.161.43.118:57820','-Dspark.driver.appUIAddress=http://10.161.43.118:4040','-Dspark.driver.host=10.161.43.118','-Dspark.eventLog.enabled=false','-Dspark.yarn.jar=hdfs://vanpghdcn1.pgdev.sap.corp:8020/data/spark-assembly-1.4.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar','-Dspark.cores.max=6',-Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=">http://10.161.43.118:57820','-Dspark.driver.appUIAddress=http://10.161.43.118:4040','-Dspark.driver.host=10.161.43.118','-Dspark.eventLog.enabled=false','-Dspark.yarn.jar=hdfs://vanpghdcn1.pgdev.sap.corp:8020/data/spark-assembly-1.4.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar','-Dspark.cores.max=6',-Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=<LOG_DIR>,org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher,--arg,'10.161.43.118:57819',--executor-memory,1024m,--executor-cores,1,--num-executors ,2,1>,<LOG_DIR>/stdout,2>,<LOG_DIR>/stderr 
2015-10-22 10:10:42,608 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.AMRMTokenSecretManager: Create AMRMToken for ApplicationAttempt: appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 
2015-10-22 10:10:42,608 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.AMRMTokenSecretManager: Creating password for appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 
2015-10-22 10:10:42,640 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher: Done launching container Container: [ContainerId: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000001, NodeId: vanpghdcn3.pgdev.sap.corp:41419, NodeHttpAddress: vanpghdcn3.pgdev.sap.corp:8042, Resource: <memory:1024, vCores:1>, Priority: 0, Token: Token { kind: ContainerToken, service: 10.165.28.145:41419 }, ] for AM appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 
2015-10-22 10:10:42,640 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 State change from ALLOCATED to LAUNCHED 
2015-10-22 10:10:43,613 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000001 Container Transitioned from ACQUIRED to RUNNING 
2015-10-22 10:10:48,176 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 (auth:SIMPLE) 
2015-10-22 10:10:48,188 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService: AM registration appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 
2015-10-22 10:10:48,188 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=hdfs IP=10.165.28.145    OPERATION=Register App Master   TARGET=ApplicationMasterService RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1445462013958_0012 APPATTEMPTID=appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 
2015-10-22 10:10:48,188 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 State change from LAUNCHED to RUNNING 
2015-10-22 10:10:48,188 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: application_1445462013958_0012 State change from ACCEPTED to RUNNING 
2015-10-22 10:10:48,632 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000002 Container Transitioned from NEW to ALLOCATED 
2015-10-22 10:10:48,632 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=hdfs OPERATION=AM Allocated Container    TARGET=SchedulerApp RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1445462013958_0012 CONTAINERID=container_1445462013958_0012_01_000002 
2015-10-22 10:10:48,632 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerNode: Assigned container container_1445462013958_0012_01_000002 of capacity <memory:2048, vCores:1> on host vanpghdcn3.pgdev.sap.corp:41419, which has 2 containers, <memory:3072, vCores:2> used and <memory:5120, vCores:6> available after allocation 
2015-10-22 10:10:48,632 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: assignedContainer application attempt=appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 container=Container: [ContainerId: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000002, NodeId: vanpghdcn3.pgdev.sap.corp:41419, NodeHttpAddress: vanpghdcn3.pgdev.sap.corp:8042, Resource: <memory:2048, vCores:1>, Priority: 1, Token: null, ] queue=default: capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:1024, vCores:1>, usedCapacity=0.041666668, absoluteUsedCapacity=0.041666668, numApps=1, numContainers=1 clusterResource=<memory:24576, vCores:24>
2015-10-22 10:10:48,633 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: Re-sorting assigned queue: root.default stats: default: capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:3072, vCores:2>, usedCapacity=0.125, absoluteUsedCapacity=0.125, numApps=1, numContainers=2 
2015-10-22 10:10:48,633 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: assignedContainer queue=root usedCapacity=0.125 absoluteUsedCapacity=0.125 used=<memory:3072, vCores:2> cluster=<memory:24576, vCores:24>
2015-10-22 10:10:48,819 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000003 Container Transitioned from NEW to ALLOCATED 
2015-10-22 10:10:48,819 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=hdfs OPERATION=AM Allocated Container    TARGET=SchedulerApp RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1445462013958_0012 CONTAINERID=container_1445462013958_0012_01_000003 
2015-10-22 10:10:48,819 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerNode: Assigned container container_1445462013958_0012_01_000003 of capacity <memory:2048, vCores:1> on host vanpghdcn2.pgdev.sap.corp:36064, which has 1 containers, <memory:2048, vCores:1> used and <memory:6144, vCores:7> available after allocation 
2015-10-22 10:10:48,819 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: assignedContainer application attempt=appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 container=Container: [ContainerId: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000003, NodeId: vanpghdcn2.pgdev.sap.corp:36064, NodeHttpAddress: vanpghdcn2.pgdev.sap.corp:8042, Resource: <memory:2048, vCores:1>, Priority: 1, Token: null, ] queue=default: capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:3072, vCores:2>, usedCapacity=0.125, absoluteUsedCapacity=0.125, numApps=1, numContainers=2 clusterResource=<memory:24576, vCores:24>
2015-10-22 10:10:48,819 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: Re-sorting assigned queue: root.default stats: default: capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:5120, vCores:3>, usedCapacity=0.20833333, absoluteUsedCapacity=0.20833333, numApps=1, numContainers=3 
2015-10-22 10:10:48,820 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: assignedContainer queue=root usedCapacity=0.20833333 absoluteUsedCapacity=0.20833333 used=<memory:5120, vCores:3> cluster=<memory:24576, vCores:24>
2015-10-22 10:10:53,253 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.NMTokenSecretManagerInRM: Sending NMToken for nodeId : vanpghdcn3.pgdev.sap.corp:41419 for container : container_1445462013958_0012_01_000002 
2015-10-22 10:10:53,255 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000002 Container Transitioned from ALLOCATED to ACQUIRED 
2015-10-22 10:10:53,256 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.NMTokenSecretManagerInRM: Sending NMToken for nodeId : vanpghdcn2.pgdev.sap.corp:36064 for container : container_1445462013958_0012_01_000003 
2015-10-22 10:10:53,257 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000003 Container Transitioned from ALLOCATED to ACQUIRED 
2015-10-22 10:10:53,643 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000002 Container Transitioned from ACQUIRED to RUNNING 
2015-10-22 10:10:53,830 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000003 Container Transitioned from ACQUIRED to RUNNING 
2015-10-22 10:10:58,282 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.AppSchedulingInfo: checking for deactivate of application :application_1445462013958_0012 
2015-10-22 10:11:08,349 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: Updating application attempt appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 with final state: FINISHING, and exit status: -1000 
2015-10-22 10:11:08,349 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 State change from RUNNING to FINAL_SAVING 
2015-10-22 10:11:08,349 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: Updating application application_1445462013958_0012 with final state: FINISHING 
2015-10-22 10:11:08,349 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: application_1445462013958_0012 State change from RUNNING to FINAL_SAVING 
2015-10-22 10:11:08,350 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore: Updating info for app: application_1445462013958_0012 
2015-10-22 10:11:08,350 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 State change from FINAL_SAVING to FINISHING 
2015-10-22 10:11:08,350 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: application_1445462013958_0012 State change from FINAL_SAVING to FINISHING 
2015-10-22 10:11:08,453 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService: application_1445462013958_0012 unregistered successfully. 
2015-10-22 10:11:08,692 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000002 Container Transitioned from RUNNING to COMPLETED 
2015-10-22 10:11:08,692 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.common.fica.FiCaSchedulerApp: Completed container: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000002 in state: COMPLETED event:FINISHED 
2015-10-22 10:11:08,692 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=hdfs OPERATION=AM Released Container TARGET=SchedulerApp RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1445462013958_0012 CONTAINERID=container_1445462013958_0012_01_000002 
2015-10-22 10:11:08,693 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerNode: Released container container_1445462013958_0012_01_000002 of capacity <memory:2048, vCores:1> on host vanpghdcn3.pgdev.sap.corp:41419, which currently has 1 containers, <memory:1024, vCores:1> used and <memory:7168, vCores:7> available, release resources=true 
2015-10-22 10:11:08,693 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: default used=<memory:3072, vCores:2> numContainers=2 user=hdfs user-resources=<memory:3072, vCores:2>
2015-10-22 10:11:08,693 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: completedContainer container=Container: [ContainerId: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000002, NodeId: vanpghdcn3.pgdev.sap.corp:41419, NodeHttpAddress: vanpghdcn3.pgdev.sap.corp:8042, Resource: <memory:2048, vCores:1>, Priority: 1, Token: Token { kind: ContainerToken, service: 10.165.28.145:41419 }, ] queue=default: capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:3072, vCores:2>, usedCapacity=0.125, absoluteUsedCapacity=0.125, numApps=1, numContainers=2 cluster=<memory:24576, vCores:24>
2015-10-22 10:11:08,693 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: completedContainer queue=root usedCapacity=0.125 absoluteUsedCapacity=0.125 used=<memory:3072, vCores:2> cluster=<memory:24576, vCores:24>
2015-10-22 10:11:08,693 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: Re-sorting completed queue: root.default stats: default: capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:3072, vCores:2>, usedCapacity=0.125, absoluteUsedCapacity=0.125, numApps=1, numContainers=2 
2015-10-22 10:11:08,693 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Application attempt appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 released container container_1445462013958_0012_01_000002 on node: host: vanpghdcn3.pgdev.sap.corp:41419 #containers=1 available=<memory:7168, vCores:7> used=<memory:1024, vCores:1> with event: FINISHED 
2015-10-22 10:11:08,704 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Socket Reader #1 for port 8050: readAndProcess from client 10.161.43.118 threw exception [java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer] 
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer 
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) 
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39) 
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) 
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197) 
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.channelRead(Server.java:2603) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.access$2800(Server.java:136) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Connection.readAndProcess(Server.java:1481) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.doRead(Server.java:771) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener$Reader.doRunLoop(Server.java:637) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener$Reader.run(Server.java:608) 
2015-10-22 10:11:08,920 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000003 Container Transitioned from RUNNING to COMPLETED 
2015-10-22 10:11:08,920 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.common.fica.FiCaSchedulerApp: Completed container: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000003 in state: COMPLETED event:FINISHED 
2015-10-22 10:11:08,920 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=hdfs OPERATION=AM Released Container TARGET=SchedulerApp RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1445462013958_0012 CONTAINERID=container_1445462013958_0012_01_000003 
2015-10-22 10:11:08,920 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerNode: Released container container_1445462013958_0012_01_000003 of capacity <memory:2048, vCores:1> on host vanpghdcn2.pgdev.sap.corp:36064, which currently has 0 containers, <memory:0, vCores:0> used and <memory:8192, vCores:8> available, release resources=true 
2015-10-22 10:11:08,920 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: default used=<memory:1024, vCores:1> numContainers=1 user=hdfs user-resources=<memory:1024, vCores:1>
2015-10-22 10:11:08,921 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: completedContainer container=Container: [ContainerId: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000003, NodeId: vanpghdcn2.pgdev.sap.corp:36064, NodeHttpAddress: vanpghdcn2.pgdev.sap.corp:8042, Resource: <memory:2048, vCores:1>, Priority: 1, Token: Token { kind: ContainerToken, service: 10.165.28.143:36064 }, ] queue=default: capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:1024, vCores:1>, usedCapacity=0.041666668, absoluteUsedCapacity=0.041666668, numApps=1, numContainers=1 cluster=<memory:24576, vCores:24>
2015-10-22 10:11:08,921 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: completedContainer queue=root usedCapacity=0.041666668 absoluteUsedCapacity=0.041666668 used=<memory:1024, vCores:1> cluster=<memory:24576, vCores:24>
2015-10-22 10:11:08,921 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: Re-sorting completed queue: root.default stats: default: capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:1024, vCores:1>, usedCapacity=0.041666668, absoluteUsedCapacity=0.041666668, numApps=1, numContainers=1 
2015-10-22 10:11:08,921 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Application attempt appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 released container container_1445462013958_0012_01_000003 on node: host: vanpghdcn2.pgdev.sap.corp:36064 #containers=0 available=<memory:8192, vCores:8> used=<memory:0, vCores:0> with event: FINISHED 
2015-10-22 10:11:09,694 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000001 Container Transitioned from RUNNING to COMPLETED 
2015-10-22 10:11:09,694 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService: Unregistering app attempt : appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 
2015-10-22 10:11:09,694 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.common.fica.FiCaSchedulerApp: Completed container: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000001 in state: COMPLETED event:FINISHED 
2015-10-22 10:11:09,694 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=hdfs OPERATION=AM Released Container TARGET=SchedulerApp RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1445462013958_0012 CONTAINERID=container_1445462013958_0012_01_000001 
2015-10-22 10:11:09,695 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerNode: Released container container_1445462013958_0012_01_000001 of capacity <memory:1024, vCores:1> on host vanpghdcn3.pgdev.sap.corp:41419, which currently has 0 containers, <memory:0, vCores:0> used and <memory:8192, vCores:8> available, release resources=true 
2015-10-22 10:11:09,695 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: default used=<memory:0, vCores:0> numContainers=0 user=hdfs user-resources=<memory:0, vCores:0>
2015-10-22 10:11:09,695 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: completedContainer container=Container: [ContainerId: container_1445462013958_0012_01_000001, NodeId: vanpghdcn3.pgdev.sap.corp:41419, NodeHttpAddress: vanpghdcn3.pgdev.sap.corp:8042, Resource: <memory:1024, vCores:1>, Priority: 0, Token: Token { kind: ContainerToken, service: 10.165.28.145:41419 }, ] queue=default: capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:0, vCores:0>, usedCapacity=0.0, absoluteUsedCapacity=0.0, numApps=1, numContainers=0 cluster=<memory:24576, vCores:24>
2015-10-22 10:11:09,695 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: completedContainer queue=root usedCapacity=0.0 absoluteUsedCapacity=0.0 used=<memory:0, vCores:0> cluster=<memory:24576, vCores:24>
2015-10-22 10:11:09,695 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: Re-sorting completed queue: root.default stats: default: capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:0, vCores:0>, usedCapacity=0.0, absoluteUsedCapacity=0.0, numApps=1, numContainers=0 
2015-10-22 10:11:09,695 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Application attempt appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 released container container_1445462013958_0012_01_000001 on node: host: vanpghdcn3.pgdev.sap.corp:41419 #containers=0 available=<memory:8192, vCores:8> used=<memory:0, vCores:0> with event: FINISHED 
2015-10-22 10:11:09,694 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.AMRMTokenSecretManager: Application finished, removing password for appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 
2015-10-22 10:11:09,696 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 State change from FINISHING to FINISHED 
2015-10-22 10:11:09,696 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: application_1445462013958_0012 State change from FINISHING to FINISHED 
2015-10-22 10:11:09,696 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Application Attempt appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 is done. finalState=FINISHED 
2015-10-22 10:11:09,696 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=hdfs OPERATION=Application Finished - Succeeded  TARGET=RMAppManager RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1445462013958_0012 
2015-10-22 10:11:09,696 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.AppSchedulingInfo: Application application_1445462013958_0012 requests cleared 
2015-10-22 10:11:09,696 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: Application removed - appId: application_1445462013958_0012 user: hdfs queue: default #user-pending-applications: 0 #user-active-applications: 0 #queue-pending-applications: 0 #queue-active-applications: 0 
2015-10-22 10:11:09,696 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: Application removed - appId: application_1445462013958_0012 user: hdfs leaf-queue of parent: root #applications: 0 
2015-10-22 10:11:09,696 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager$ApplicationSummary: appId=application_1445462013958_0012,name=Sparca Application,user=hdfs,queue=default,state=FINISHED,trackingUrl=http://vanpghdcn1:8088/proxy/application_1445462013958_0012/,appMasterHost=10.165.28.145,startTime=1445533842429,finishTime=1445533868349,finalStatus=SUCCEEDED,memorySeconds=109990,vcoreSeconds=67,preemptedAMContainers=0,preemptedNonAMContainers=0,preemptedResources=<memory:0\, vCores:0>,applicationType=SPARK 
2015-10-22 10:11:09,696 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher: Cleaning master appattempt_1445462013958_0012_000001 
2015-10-22 10:11:10,719 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Null container completed... 
2015-10-22 10:11:10,925 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Null container completed...
```

It's worth mentioning that 10.161.43.118 is the machine that I'm running my eclipse on. And my test app is just reading a csv into a dataframe and doing a count.

Comment: You have two answers and you didn't say a thing..

Answer (score 1):

How big is your file size ?
This says, some kind of client side networking issue which temporarily caused the communication issue between the host and the Endpoint.
If the files size is big enough, then it takes long time to stream the data over the TCP channel and the connection can not be made alive for a long time and gets reset. Hope, this answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that there are some firewall issues between the the two. I'd start by verifying that your cluster machines & are able to talk to the driver host.